# Equivalent of Servlet Filter for Jersey / JAX-RS / REST resources?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jersey, jax-rs

In a regular Web Application, I can assign a chain of Filters to various paths for aspects such as Authentication, Authorization, Errors, Logging and more.

The advantage is that I write servlets to focus on core functionality without worrying about infrastructure aspects.  I can write orthogonal, cross-cutting Filters to authenticate, authorize, etc.  Then I can weave them in web.xml.  Looking at web.xml is enough to assure me that there are no holes in my application.

Is this possible in JAX-RS or Jersey?  If not, what is my best bet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not identical to servlet filters, Jersey supports ContainerResponseFilter and ContainerRequestFilter. These get called for *all* requests, so you have to do any URL matching in code.

The ResourceFilter was removed in Jersey 2.

Comment: i tried to edit your answer for completeness but pedants did not allow me to. could you please edit your answer to also include a mentino to ResourceFilter which is a better way to filter because it is on a per-resource basis. i am accepting your answer in the hope that you will add this information too. thanks :)

Comment: The above link is broken