# Authentication in multiple methods with JAX-RS/Jersey - How to keep it clean?

Tags: java, authentication, jersey, jax-ws

I'm working on a web service written in Java using JAX-RS/Jersey and Spring.

The WS authenticates a user when he or she logs in and returns an access key which has a limited lifespan. Most of the available methods require a valid "access key + userId" combination.

For all of the available methods I am using @FormParam to retrieve POST parameters, and the response is in JSON. What I am trying to figure out is how to avoid having to type out

```
@FormParam("userId") final Integer userId,
@FormParam("accessKey") final String accessKey
```

and manually invoke my authentication method for each of the probably 20 methods I will have that require authentication. This is especially cumbersome because I will then also have to add code to handle e.g. expired access keys.

Is there another way to go about retrieving the two parameters above and performing authentication so I can keep my methods clean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using Jersey, you can use servlet-filter-like APIs to DRY up your code. Check out:

- [Equivalent of Servlet Filter for Jersey / JAX-RS / REST resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738366/equivalent-of-servlet-filter-for-jersey-jax-rs-rest-resources)
- [How does one intercept a request during the Jersey lifecycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358213/how-does-one-intercept-a-request-during-the-jersey-lifecycle)
- [`ContainerRequestFilter`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html)

Comment: Thanks Matt! This looks like just what I needed

Comment: I've set up the filters and it seems to be working well! I've accepted your answer, thanks again.