# javax servlet filter vs jersey filter

Tags: java, servlets, jersey

I'm planning on writing a servlet application (meant for deployment with OSGI) and use some filters for HTTP header pre-processing. While originally settled on the javax.servlet filter implementation, it occured to me that I actually don't know why/when one would choose to use that vs the Jersey ContainerRequestFilter. 
Granted the latter comes with some pre-built filters, but arguably so does the former (eg Cors filter).
Thus, what should be considered when choosing which API to use? Are there specific cases when one should not be used in favor of the other?

Comment: This question is not the same as [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738366/equivalent-of-servlet-filter-for-jersey-jax-rs-rest-resources), in that it does not ask whether it is possible nor which is the best, but rather what should one consider when choosing. This is also not answered on the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you decide, you *will* be using a javax.servlet based Filter implementation, since it is the base interface for every `Filter` you use in Java EE.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html

Now, Jersey comes with an implementation that adds some functionality (access to your `ContainerRequestContext` or whatever you would need inside your Jersey application).  Are you using Jersey already in your application?  Then go for it, if not I would not bother (at least a priori and without further information) and just go for the most simple possible implementation of `javax.servlet.Filter` and put it straight into my web.xml

Comment: Thanks. So, accessing the request context is clearly also possible from a Filter implementation (.getHeader(), .getParameter(), etc), but i suppose that ContainerRequestContext provides a bit more finesse in doing so by having various inbuilt getters, etc.

Comment: @Jorge_B -  I don't see that ContainerRequestFilter extends the servlet Filter interface. Can you please explain what you mean by: "Whatever you decide, you will be using a javax.servlet based Filter implementation, since it is the base interface for every Filter you use in Java EE.". Thanks!

Comment: I stand corrected, Jersey implementation does not extend javax.servlet.Filter.  In that case you have only the reference to the ContainerRequestContext to interact with the application behavior, and no way to alter the filter chain as in a normal Filter.  Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on @elanh question because I am confused as well ?

Answer (score 2):

From https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-en/cn/part1/chapter12/server_side_filters.html

[...] servlet filters wrap around servlet processing and are run in the same Java call stack. Because JAX-RS has an asynchronous API, JAX-RS filters cannot run in the same Java call stack. Each request filter runs to completion before the JAX-RS method is invoked. [...]

I think, this is a key difference, that should be considered, when choosing the one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with JAX-RS filters is that your are not in control to execute the filter chain

```
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Because my problem is now to shift a Servlet Filter to a JAX-RS filter but the current Servlet Filter calls the whole filter chain in order to check in the end the response and its status. This is not possible with a JAX-RS filter from my point of view.

Comment: Okay, now I've grasped that a ContainerResponseFilter can be used to check the filter chain at the end.

Comment: By this do you mean that one can see the filters registered and the order in which they are registered?