# How to modify query param in postfilter in Jersey 2

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, servlet-filters, query-string

I am trying to modify the query param in a post-matching filter. I cannot do this in pre-matching filter as the filter logic depends on the resource class and method annotations. I am using Jersey 2.x and Spring Boot.

I cannot modify the query param by calling `setRequestUri` as it is allowed only in pre-matching filter ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939919/how-to-modify-queryparam-and-pathparam-in-jersey-2)).

I do not want to set an attribute, as that would require changing all existing services to read from the attribute. If no other option is available, I might need to go with the attribute approach.

Filter is registered by calling `ResourceConfig#register(cls, priority)`

The filter class implements `ContainerRequestFilter`.

```java
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        // modifiedUri is the uri with modified query params
        // requestContext.setRequestUri(modifiedUri) ==> Throws IllegalStateException - "Method could be called only in pre-matching request filter."
    }
}
```

I tried searching online and found solutions that sets request attributes.
I found another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413129/modify-request-parameter-with-servlet-filter) which suggests creating a wrapper (`HttpServletRequestWrapper`). But in the above filter, I do not have access to the `filterChain`. Since the filter requires access to the resource class and resource method annotations, I believe I need to use a Jersey filter and cannot use the Servlet filter ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497349/javax-servlet-filter-vs-jersey-filter)).

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557134/how-to-modify-query-params-in-a-jersey-filter